# Error installing chaincode while deploying .bna file using Hyperledger Composer on local machine with Fabric 1.0.0 Production Release

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am following the my-network tutorial from the Hyperledger Composer docs and am getting the following error when deploying the .bna file to Fabric.

The command I use is:

```
composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
```

Error message:

```
✖ Deploying business network definition. This may take a minute...

Error: error trying deploy. Error: error trying install chaincode. Error: Connect Failed
Command failed
```

I am on OSX and have all the required preliminaries.

Comment: Connect failed means composer cannot connect to a fabric defined by the connection profile hlfv1. Can you post the following
1. The output from the command 'docker ps' to show the containers that are  providing the fabric runtime
2. The contents of connection.json which can be found in the directory '.composer-connection-profiles/hlfv1' off of your home directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same error - assuming you are following the [Hyperledger Composer Developer Guide](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html).

I think this error comes about because at the end of [installing the developer environment](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html) you run a command to stop and tear down the Fabric, but then the Developer Guide does not instruct you to restart it.

To fix I changed back to the fabric-tools directory and re-started Fabric:

```
cd ../..
./startFabric.sh
```

Returning to the original directory I then tried deploying it again:

```
cd my-network/dist/
composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
```

This got me to the `Command succeeded` all clear the guide tells you to expect.

Good luck.

Comment: @aabdulwahed I think this is a different error?  The original error is `Error: Connect Failed`, yours is `Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity`?  Would this be better with a fresh question?

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I thought the command would spin the fabric containers itself. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory which contains the bna file, usually; it is under your sample folder\dist

Then run the following:

```
$ composer network install -a my-network.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
```